What is a good way to create a FormGroup using the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle?
I'm not convinced by the way formgroups are created in Angular.
I create forms like this:
let form = this._formBuilder.group({
              nameAditionalCtrl: [adicional.nameAditional, [Validators.required]],
              typeClientPriceCtrl: [parseInt(adicional.typeClientPrice,10), [Validators.required]],
              priceClient: [parseInt(adicional.priceClient,10), [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(5)]],
              who: [parseInt(adicional.who,10), [Validators.required]],
              typeRelayPrice: [parseInt(adicional.typeRelayPrice,10), Validators.required],
              relayPrice: [parseInt(adicional.relayPrice,10), Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]
            })

but lately I have had a large number of fields in the forms, then i started to create forms like this
this.form = this.formBuilder.group(this.data);

"data" is a variable that I define manually. This is easy for me because I use this object for multiple purposes.
data is a variable that I load from an endpoint. When I submit the form, I populate data with the form values and send this object like this.
Object.keys(this.data).forEach(prop=>{
      fd.append(prop, this.form[prop]);
    })   

But I suspect this is not the best way to manipulate a form.
Is there a cleaner way to do this avoiding repeating code?

Watch this video to get an idea.Pretty advanced stuff.

Seems like this is opinion-based. IMHO, the Angular forms follow the DRY principles, there is no "useless" repitition. The FormBuilder narrows it down to the bare minimum necessary to define a form group.

I usually make a function that accepts a formBuilder as standalone util function and pass that from inside the component

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
